# Firebase cloud function 1.0, no auth information for current user

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I just upgraded to firebase cloud functions 1.0 and since there is not `event` parameter there is no `event.auth.variable.uid` which used to give information about current user(although it was undocumented).

Firebase 1.0 has new context parameter which is something like

```
{ service: 'firebaseio.com',
 name: 'projects/_/<ref>/pushId5' },
 authType: 'ADMIN',
 params: { pushId: 'pushId5' } }
```

How do I get current user information in new firebase functions sdk?

Comment: According to the new docs, there should be a [context.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#.auth) object

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs:

> `EventContext.auth` V1.0.0 introduces two new properties for accessing user information, including permissions, for the user that triggered a function.
>
> `EventContext.auth` Contains information such as `uid` and the authenticated user's auth token.
>
> `EventContext.authType` Contains permissions levels, allowing you to detect whether the user is an admin user, for example.

Developers using the undocumented `event.auth` fields should update any related code to use these new properties.

Therefore to get information about the user, do the following:

```
exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path/with/{id}').onWrite((data, context) => {
const authVar = context.auth.uid;
const authType = context.authType.ADMIN;

});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#sdk_changes_by_trigger_type

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#.authType

Answer (score 1):

My bad, while testing function in `functions:shell` i was not passing any `auth` parameter. I actually needed to pass it like this

```
myFunc(newObject, {auth: {uid: 'abcd'}})
```

then this auth id can be retrieved using `context.auth.uid`

Comment: I just tried that and the uid is still not available in `context.auth.uid`. Did the API for that changed?